# @EnabledIf is not skipping test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, junit5

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestService {


@Test
@EnabledIf("Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(\"Asia/Kolkata\")).getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY")
public void test() {
System.out.println("The day is Monday");
}


}
```

running using `mvn -Dtest=TestService test`

@EnabledIf is not working, it is executing the test even the day is not Monday

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-custom) the `@EnabledIf` annotation does **not** support arbitrary expression - you can only define either the name of a method in the test class or the fully qualified name of a method outside of the test class. This method **must** return a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two big problems:

First, the test class is annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and (because the test runs) the test method is annotated with `@org.junit.Test`

This means that the test is running using the JUnit4 testing framework and JUnit4 knows nothing about the `@EnabledIf` annotation and ignores it.

If you want to use the `@EnabledIf` annotation you **must** make your test into a JUnit5 test and for that you must change your test class to

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIf;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestService {

    @Test
    @EnabledIf("Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(\"Asia/Kolkata\")).getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("The day is Monday");
    }

}
```

Because of the second problem that doesn't completely solve your problem. The [documentation for `@EnabledIf`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-custom) states:

> A container or test may be enabled or disabled based **on the boolean return of a method** via the @EnabledIf and @DisabledIf annotations. **The method is provided to the annotation via its name**.

That means that you cannot provide some arbitrary expression as the argument of the `@EnabledIf` annotation - you need to implement the expression in a method.

When adding that method your test class might look like this:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIf;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestService {

    @Test
    @EnabledIf("onMonday")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("The day is Monday");
    }

    static boolean onMonday() {
        return Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
    }

}
```

---

If however you intended to use `org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.EnabledIf` (instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.condition.EnabledIf` - unfortunately your question is not clear about that) then you need to adjust the imports and provide a SpEL-Expression for the condition:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.EnabledIf;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestService {

    @Test
    @EnabledIf("#{T(java.time.Instant).now().atZone(T(java.time.ZoneId).of(\"Asia/Kolkata\")).getDayOfWeek() == T(java.time.DayOfWeek).MONDAY}")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("The day is Monday");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're correct about JUnit 4 vs JUnit Jupiter regarding `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, but I think the intent is to use a SpEL expression with Spring's [`@EnabledIf` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/EnabledIf.html).

Comment: @SamBrannen thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer to include an example for the `@org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.EnabledIf` annotation too.

Comment: The SpEL expression will not work like that, since fully qualified types have to be used. The expression would need to be `#{"T(java.time.Instant).now().atZone(T(java.time.ZoneId).of('Asia/Kolkata')).getDayOfWeek() == T(java.time.DayOfWeek).WEDNESDAY"}`